# Why can I not register to events passed as arguments?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, nullreferenceexception

This is my code:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public class MyClass1{

    event Action _myEvent;

    public MyClass1(){
        var m = new MyClass2(_myEvent);
        _myEvent();
    }

}

public class MyClass2{
    public MyClass2(Action _event){
        _event += MyFunction;
    }

    void MyFunction(){
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
    }
}

class Program
{

static void Main()
    {
        var m = new MyClass1();
    }
}
```

It seems MyClass2 is not registering to the passed argument _myEvent. Invoking _myEvent causes a NullReferenceException even though MyClass2 should be subscribed. If I make _myEvent public and let MyClass2 register to it directly without using the event argument passed to it, it works correctly. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How do you suppose I create it? I've never seen anyone "create" an event. If I make the event public and register to it directly without using the argument everything works fine though.

Comment: Which part do you make public?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot The answer in the question you posted does not answer my question.

Comment: try `public MyClass2(ref  Action _event)`

Comment: That worked but why do I need to pass it by reference? Isn't a delegate a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `NullReferenceException` because `_myEvent` is null after the return from `MyClass2` constructor.

In the constructor for `MyClass2`, when you do `_event += MyFunction`, that is effectively shorthand for:

```
_event = (Action)Delegate.Combine(_event, (Action)MyFunction);
```

So now inside the constructor you have a completely new reference which won't get passed back unless you add the `ref` keyword to the parameter.

Comment: `_event = Delegate.Combine(_event, (Action)MyFunction);` if you want it to compile.

Comment: @sstan Almost, but not quite, but I edited a compilable version in.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with references. Try:

`public MyClass2(ref Action _event)`

**Explanation**:

When the compiler compiles the code, it generates the `event` into 2 methods: `add_YourEvent` and `remove_YourEvent` and **a private delegate containing the reference to the head** of the list of registered delegates.

The problem arises because when you pass your object as parameter to the method, they're actually **2 different memory blocks**. Changes to the reference inside the method does not affect your variable declared in your `MyClass1`. So when this line is executed:

```
_event += MyFunction;
```

The reference is changed from `null` to a reference to a delegate, but this only affects the passed in parameter. Your variable's reference (declared in `MyClass1`) does not change.

Comment: When `_event += MyFunction;` is called, `_event` is just a delegate, not an event, despite its name.  So it's not really calling the `add_YourEvent` method in this case.